# Azure API M - Local Development

Tags: azure-api-management

What is the story for local development for API M? I want to pull down a local copy of API M for local developers to build their API's against, is that possible (also configuring the backend resources to local copies of the code that would run in the cloud)?

I was thinking maybe a `docker` image of API M, configured for running locally on a developer machine for our environment. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, dev tools support is not there yet, but you can run it locally: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/self-hosted-gateway-overview. It still requires connection to cloud though and configuration must be done either through Azure Portal or ARM.

Comment: can you set it up to target functions running locally?  Or is just the APIM running locally?

Comment: APIM gateway would not care where backend is, really. As long as this backend is reachable from container where APIM is running everything should be fine.

Comment: surprised there seemly no documentation / references as to how you would run APIM locally vs local functions.  

Makes me think no one is really using APIM?

Comment: Because there is not much specific about APIM when used locally or outside of Azure. We have guidance on how to use it inside Docker (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/how-to-deploy-self-hosted-gateway-docker), or Kubernetes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/how-to-deploy-self-hosted-gateway-kubernetes). Once that is done, the rest is for those platforms to describe. Here is networking overview for Docker: https://docs.docker.com/network/, and for Kubernetes: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/.

Comment: Sounds like you work on APIM? Would it be possible to setup a short call with you ( or one of your colleagues) to discuss developer experience for our use case?

Comment: Sure. The best way to do that is through support request, open one up, provide feedback there, say that you want to  talk to product group, possibly link that SO thread.